# Ive got a logic error in my program. Can anyone spot whats wrong?

Tags: logic

The list below is supposed to be result of my program. Though, for #2 I get "Homer opens the door". I dont know if im staring right at the error. I've been studying the code for a while and being sleepy definitely doesnt help. Any help is appreciated!

1. //Bart locks the door.
2. //Homer tries to open the door, but can't because its locked.
3. //Homer unlocks the door.
4. //Homer opens the door.
5. //Bart tries to open the door, but can't because its already open.
6. //Marge closes the door.
7. //Homer tries to close the door, but can't because it is already
   closed.
8. //Lisa opens the door.
9. //Abraham tries to lock the door, but can't because its open.
10. //Marge closes the door.
11. //Abraham locks the door.
12. //Bart tries to open the door, but can't because its locked.
13. //Lisa tries to open the door, but can't because its locked.
14. //Homer tries to open the door, but can't because its locked.
15. //Abraham unlocks the door.
16. //Homer opens the door.
17. //Marge closes the door.

    ```
    //in a separate method:

    bart.lockDoor();
    homer.openDoor();
    homer.unlockDoor();
    homer.openDoor();
    bart.openDoor();
    marge.closeDoor();
    homer.closeDoor();
    lisa.openDoor();
    abraham.unlockDoor();
    marge.closeDoor();
    abraham.lockDoor();
    bart.openDoor();
    lisa.openDoor();
    homer.openDoor();
    abraham.unlockDoor();
    homer.openDoor();
    marge.closeDoor();

     boolean locked;
     boolean open;

     public void lockDoor()
    {
        if(locked == true)
            out.println( name + " tries to lock the door, but can't because its already locked.");
            else
                if(open == false)
                {
                    locked = true;
                    out.println( name + " locks the door.");

                }
    }

    public void unlockDoor()
    {
        if(open == true)
            out.println( name + " tries to unlock the door, but can't because its open.");
                else
                    if(locked == false)
                        out.println( name + " tries to unlock the door, but can't because its already unlocked.");
                        else
                            if(locked == true)
                            {
                                out.println( name + " unlocks the door.");
                                locked = false;
                            }

    }

    public void openDoor()
    {
        if(open == true)
            out.println( name + " tries to open the door, but can't because its already open.");
            else
                if( locked == true )
                    out.println( name + " tries to open the door, but can't because its locked.");
                    else
                        if(locked == false)
                        {
                            out.println( name + " opened the door.");
                            open = true;
                        }

    }

    public void closeDoor()
    {
        if(open == false)
            out.println( name + " tries to close the door, but can't because its already closed.");
            else
            {
                if(open == true)
                {
                    out.println( name + " closed the door.");
                    open = false;
                }

            }
    }
    ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify language or a complete program, but it looks like the problem is that each person has (effectively) their own door, independent of each other person's door, as each person has their own locked/open flags to track their door.

If you want there to only be a single door, you need to get all the people to share a single locked and single open flag.  Depending on the language you are using, you may be able to do that by making the flags `static`.  Alternately, you could put them in a separate 'door' object and have all the 'people' objects refer that 'door'

Comment: my bad, Im working in java. as i mentioned before im kinda tired.. anyways that worked! thanks